Error: Program is not executable after I launch client to interact with helloworld.sol
This is in reference to the following repo: https://github.com/solana-labs/example-helloworld/
So after a few hiccups I managed to compile helloworld.so
I then deployed that beast using:
solana program deploy ~/example-helloworld/dist/program/helloworld.so
So far so good:
Program Id: 8MCcSGEEALayT53wgLB8gLFaWyxDTV16xYWg7d89Dr4a
I install all dependencies using npm install 
And I fire it up:
candid@DESKTOP-5D7VSM9:~/example-helloworld$ npm run start

> helloworld@0.0.1 start
> ts-node src/client/main.ts

Let's say hello to a Solana account...
Connection to cluster established: http://localhost:8899 { 'feature-set': 3352961542, 'solana-core': '1.18.4' }
Using account 6sgA73Uu6Ww8sFAt4h48ruqYgtuDK9F4Q3px72qnr7mw containing 500000031.0946681 SOL to pay for fees
Error: Program is not executable
    at /home/candid/example-helloworld/src/client/hello_world.ts:159:11
    at Generator.next (<anonymous>)
    at fulfilled (/home/candid/example-helloworld/src/client/hello_world.ts:30:58)
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)
candid@DESKTOP-5D7VSM9:~/example-helloworld$ 


What am I missing here?

All looks correct... can you double-check that your client is checking 8MCcSGEEALayT53wgLB8gLFaWyxDTV16xYWg7d89Dr4a at https://github.com/solana-labs/example-helloworld/blob/354e890721068fa5d38e16f380bf994e1c678eb7/src/client/hello_world.ts#L149 or dump the output of that call?

I ended up getting everything to work when I redeployed
